# preview image upload more than one input

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 input type file with preview of images
and problem is when i try to upload one image for one input it will effect on all other input here is my code :

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />    
<img class="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img class="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img class="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.blah')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're telling it to set all elements with class "blah" to that image on load. If you only want to set one of them, you need to tell it that somehow. Each input element needs to know which img element it's supposed to update. They could share some class or data attribute. Or be wrapped in a div together (or just say "update my previous sibling" but that's pretty fragile.)

Comment: Not `$('.blah')`, it should be next element of input

Comment: do you mean that i use something like data-preview in attr?

Comment: @mehrdad I posted one solution, check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(input).next()
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img class="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img class="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img class="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
```

You should not directly append to .blah, it should be next element of current input

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" /> -->
        <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
        <style>
        img{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type='file' data-result='file1' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img name='file1' class="blah" src="Tulips.jpg" alt="your image" />
        <input type='file' data-result='file2' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img name='file2' class="blah" src="Tulips.jpg" alt="your image" />
        <input type='file' data-result='file3' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img name='file3' class="blah" src="Tulips.jpg" alt="your image" />

        <script>

            function readURL(input) {
                debugger
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    var imageElementName= input.getAttribute('data-result');
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                       debugger
                      //var imageElementName= input.getAttribute('data-result');
                        var el=document.getElementsByName(imageElementName);
                        el[0].setAttribute('src',reader.result);
                        // $('.blah')
                        //     .attr('src', e.target.result);
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```